# java network i/o blocking or not?

Tags: networking, io, blocking

Hopefully this is a quick and easy question about BufferedOutputStreams and DataOutputStreams in java.

When I write bytes to the output stream like

```
myBufferedOutputStream.write(array);
myDataOutputStream.write(array);
```

Do these methods write them instantly to the stream and return or do they ever block?

I did not see anything in the core java docs, but perhaps my question doesn't make sense because writes never block?

Someone please set me straight.

Thanks,
jbu

Answer (score 3):

Peter's answer was the best, but it was vitiated by starting out with misinformation: no, it does not "depend on the implementation". The whole point of buffering is to soften the impact of blocking, but when the buffer is full and the output hardware not ready, write() WILL block. But since it is buffered, it will block far less often and with far less impact on throughput than a plain vanilla OutputStream. Buffering is a quick and easy way to make a big improvement in performance.

Answer (score 1):

All of the read and write methods in `java.io.*` have the potential to block. None support asynchronous I/O. For reading, it must be implemented manually using [.available()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) or a similar mechanism. For writing, well, you're on your own.

Answer (score 1):

The API in the package java.io.* is potential to block. However, there´s a special API called Java NIO (New I/O or Non-blocking I/O) that you should use for aynchronous I/O.

Look at the package java.nio.*
You can find some examples here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on the implementation.  If you're using something like `BufferedOutputStream`, a call to `write()` will likely not "block" since the class provides buffering for performance.

However, if using `FileOutputStream`, the write call may block depending on how busy/available the I/O resources are on the system, since a call to `write()` may actually trigger an I/O operation at that time, which takes time to complete.